Thingsboard PE cloud edition - home page navigation issues
Landing on the 'Homepage' for my TB cloud prototype on a desktop PC allows me to navigate to other dashboards using widget actions.
However when accessing TB via Apple mobile app the widget navigations do not load different dashboards. The timeout spinning wheel displays and never actually takes you to another dashboard.
If the user has a default dashboard other than the home page then navigation works using either widget actions or the drop down dashboard list.
This seems to only be a problem when trying to navigate away from the home page. If the same dashboard is the default for a user then navigation via the widget actions works successfully.
Have changed dashboard states to / from default with no success. Have changed the home dashboard to another board again no success.
Has anyone else had this issue or is there a way to create a navigation drop down list on the homepage for mobile devices?
